# How to use an Angular 2 aux routing outlet without changing address history

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Im developing an angular 2 app. I have been using it since it was in alpha. I have searched and searched for an answer for this. I have an app that will load other pages in a modal from a main page. The main page is an component and the page to be loaded is also a component. I have tried doing with the DynamicComponentLoader and i have had mixed results. So I am trying to do this as an aux route everything works as expected however my address bar history is updating to the aux route. I dont want this behavior I want the address bar to remain unchanged for the aux route. Is there a way to turn this feature off for certain routes? or is there a better method to do what Im trying to do.

Comment: As far as I know - no. That's what the router does, synchronizing between URL and view. What's the problem with DCL?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer DCL is loading a component that uses jqgrid. There are parts jqgrid that rely on an id of a dom element to work correctly. The element is not in the dom yet when the component code is being called so it fails. But if the component is part of the main page everything works as expected.

Comment: The router uses `DynamicComponentLoader`. I wouldn't expect a different behavior. Actually DCL is deprecated. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468